# The IT manager asks Development team for a status report describing the progress throughout the Sprint

Tags: scrum, scrum-master

I had a question during PSM1 assessment:

> The IT manager asks Development team for a status report describing the progress throughout the Sprint. The Development team asks the Scrum Master for advice. The Scrum Master should/will:
>   (Select two best options)

- Create and deliver the report to the manager herself.
- Tell the development team to figure it out themselves
- Tell the development team to fit the report into the Sprint Backlog.
- Talk to the IT manager and explain that the progress in Scrum comes from inspecting an increment at the Sprint Review.
- Ask the Product Owner to send the manager the report.

Can anyone suggest me proper answer out of given options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Status reports are not a thing in Scrum. The "manager" can be either a shareholder to the Product Owner, in which case they'll be updated through that channel, or they can be hands-off and only manage what is left, i.e. the organisation, not the projects.

Either way, the correct answer is:

> Talk to the IT manager and explain that the progress in Scrum comes from inspecting an increment at the Sprint Review.

If I'd have to pick a second fit, I'd pick "Create and deliver the report to the manager herself", because the data is all there. The board and burndown chart (or whatever the team uses to visualize progress) should be updated daily and if the manager is not happy with that visualization, maybe because the physical board is in a different building or the tool is not accessible to them, I would see it as the Scrum Masters job to present the same data in another visualization to the manager. Maybe as a screenshot of the board or automated email or graph of the burndown.

Comment: where is the "point out the giant charts on the wall that the manager can see just fine with their own eyes" option?

Answer (score 1):

As per scrum guide:
Monitoring Progress Toward a Goal
At any point in time, the total work remaining to reach a goal can be summed.
The Product Owner tracks this total work remaining at least every Sprint Review.
The Product Owner compares this amount with work remaining at previous Sprint Reviews to assess progress toward completing projected work by the desired time for the goal.
This information is made transparent to all stakeholders.

I would go with PO to provide the report if it is absolutely a necessity in the organisation. SM can definitely coach the organisation on inspect & adapt and how delivery is more important then reports and also making sure the artifacts are transparent to everyone.